# View PDF File From Android ListView

Tags: android, listview, pdfrenderer

I have a list of PDF files in my assets folder. What I want is to put these PDF files in a ListView and whenever I click an item in the ListView, the PDF file would be open/rendered. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

You need to create a ListView, an Adapter, and PDFRendarer.

- In Listview show the names of PDF.
- OnItemClick of the list, open the
  PDF using PDFRendarer.